# Show task in view (started, success, failed)

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I successfully set my django server and have celery linked with it. I can show all the task in the administration interface in the DjCelery tables.

But I want to be able to display some similar information in one of my view. How can I browse this table to get all the information about the task listed ? Is it any SQL request or python equivalent that I can put in my views.py file to get all those task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is displayed in the admin can be displayed in a custom view, as the admin only displays data available in the database. See the github [source](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/admin.py#L226) to see which models are registered for the admin.

As the task state is stored in the model `TaskState` you can fetch the task status via the following query:

```
from djcelery.models import TaskState

task_states = TaskState.objects.all()
for state in task_states:
    print state.name
    print state.state
```